# write CSS to style list items as shown in image

Tags: css, html-lists

I have no idea about CSS, please help me to write CSS to make look the list items as in the image. These are 3 list items here but it's dynamic. I tried to play around with  but it's the last time I am working with CSS so I do not want to put too much into it, what looks like fairly simple task. Please help.

[This is how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPdkP.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

```
li {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
.style {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #15dfc8;
  margin-right:20px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:
It will look more like you want it when the fonts from your site are applied

```css
.lines, .line{
display:flex;
}

.lines{
flex-direction: column;
gap: 10px;
}

.line{
align-items: center;
gap: 5px;
}

.number{
padding: 3px 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #15dfc8;
}
```

```html
<div class="lines">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="number">45</div>
    <div class="text">Fit (Very Good)</div>
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <div class="number">46</div>
    <div class="text">Fit (Very Good)</div>
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <div class="number" style="background-color: lightgray;">47</div>
    <div class="text">Fit (Good)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```